# populating drop down using database Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I followed the instruction from another stackoverflow, but somehow it end up the same, the list didn't drop.
so what did I do wrong to be exact?[image]

Here's my model :

```
class Fakultas(models.Model):
    fakul = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

    def __str__(self): return self.fakul


class Userdata(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Fakultas,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default= 1)
    is_voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):return self.user.username
```

Here is my Form :

```
class UserFakultas(forms.ModelForm):

    faculty = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Userdata
        fields =['faculty']

        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['faculty'].choices = [(faculty) for faculty in Fakultas.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allways use two values in choices and it works corectly:
and You need to asign that field again in **init**:

```
choices=[(faculty.id, faculty) for faculty in Fakultas.objects.all()]
self.fields['faculty'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), choices=choices)
```

First value(faculty.id) is id which will be passed in POST and second is for display in form.